# Discord Bot Random Replies

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm currently new at Nodejs. I want to make a discord bot that can reply to a random message. For now, I'm just trying to copy-paste code from the internet. Here's my code :

```
client.on('message' , function (message){
 if (message.content == '!hi') 
 {
     var roll =(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1);
     if (roll == 1)
     {
         message.reply('hello');
     }
     else 
     {
         message.reply('how are you?');
     }
     
 }
```

});

I have no problem with code, but I want to add another reply besides "hello" & "how are you?". I would glad if you can show me the error within my current code. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create an array of possible responses like:

```
const randomResponse = [ "Hi!", "How are you?", "Nice to meet you!", "Have a nice day!", "What's up?" ]
```

and use a tool like [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) for pick a random entry from the array

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

const randomResponse = [ "Hi!", "How are you?", "Nice to meet you!", "Have a nice day!", "What's up?" ]

client.on('message' , function (message){
 if (message.content.startsWith("!hi")) 
 {
  message.reply(_.sample(randomResponse))
 }
})
```